# Create database by C# code with SQL authentication

Tags: c#, sql-server

I want to create a database by C# code and I want to authenticate it with SQL Server (I mean I want to define username and password for it)

How can I do that?

Comment: Those are two totally different steps - first create the database (`CREATE DATABASE`), and then you need to define a login on your SQL Server (`CREATE LOGIN`) and then you even need a third step - create a user inside your database

Comment: Thanks, but i recieve an error:"User doesnt have permission to do this".how can i create user for database?

Answer (score 0):

It really is a two step process and it also depends on the security of your SQL Server box.  For instance, is SQL Server configured to use mixed mode authentication or windows authentication?  Once you find that out, you will know why you are getting this error, its a security error.  The user used to create the db should have db admin rights on the db server.
If you plan to use windows authentication, have that user be part of the sysadmin group on the db server or at least give him / her rights to CREATE.

Once you take care of your security measures it is a simple process to create a user inside of this db.